# How to generate unique names from Python list and str

Tags: python, string, list

```
str = "Adward"
list =["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z"]
```

I want to generate new names by removing two letters from `str` at index 1 and 4, and I want to insert new letter from list to generate new unique names

Example: `Aawaad`

Comment: what is the actual issue? Did you try to code it?

Comment: long way idea:
https://pythonexamples.org/python-string-replace-character-at-specific-position/

combine that with 

generate random integer called rand_Integer to use it at str[rand_Integer] to replace the characters of the word with Given_List[rand_Integer] to generate new words.

Now, the probability would be factorial of (length of list-2) for the 'for' loop to be run.


(Please don't use reserved works like list as a variable for your list of characters)

Comment: def prepend(list, str): 
      
    # Using format() 
    str += '{0}'
    list = [str.format(i) for i in list] 
    return(list) 
  
# Driver function 
str = "Adward"
list = ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z"]
print(prepend(list, str))

Comment: @LoveGIS, OP doesn't want to increase the character length, just the 1st and 4th position of the given string needs to be replaced with random integers of the list of alphabets.

Comment: Thanks for answering follow-up questions to your question, but please instead [edit] your question to add any relevant information. Any question on SO should make sense on its own so that other users finding this question in the future won't have to dig through all the comments to understand your post. Also search engines will do a better job of finding your post if everything is at the right place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- from the base string, create a list to be able to mutate its content
- replace the position `1` and `4` with random chars from the possible values
- return as a string

To just get random names do the following, you get twice the same before exhausting them all

```
from random import choice
from string import ascii_lowercase # easier than typing the alphabet

def generate(str_base, values):
    base = list(str_base)
    base[1] = choice(values)
    base[4] = choice(values)
    return "".join(base)

s = "Adward"
for i in range(10):
    print(generate(s, ascii_lowercase))
```

If you want to generate the 26*26 = 676 different ones do

```
from itertools import product
from string import ascii_lowercase  # easier than typing the alphabet


def generate_all(str_base, values):
    base = list(str_base)
    for v1, v2 in product(values, repeat=2):
        base[1] = v1
        base[4] = v2
        yield "".join(base)
```

---

#### Note

Never name variable using built-in names, as `str` or `list`

Comment: Your code doesn't generate Unique words.

I tried with range(676) and got this word twice, didn't check for others. "Avwaad"

Comment: @azro and @ raja77  thank you, I really appreciate your help. It works fine as I was thinking!

Answer (score -1):

```
GivenString = "Adward"

listOfChars =["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z"]
GivenStringList=[]
print(GivenString)
for i in range(0,len(listOfChars)):
    for j in range(0, len(listOfChars)):

        GivenString = GivenString[:1] + listOfChars[i] + GivenString[2:4] + listOfChars[j] + GivenString[5:]
        GivenStringList.append(GivenString)
print(GivenStringList)
```

print(len(GivenStringList))

The result is:

```
Adward #Original word
['Aawaad', 'Aawabd', 'Aawacd', 'Aawadd', 'Aawaed', 'Aawafd', 'Aawagd', 'Aawahd', 'Aawaid', 'Aawajd', 'Aawakd', 'Aawald', 'Aawamd', 'Aawand', 'Aawaod', 'Aawapd', 'Aawaqd', 'Aaward', 'Aawasd', 'Aawatd', 'Aawaud', 'Aawavd', 'Aawawd', 'Aawaxd', 'Aawayd', 'Aawazd', 'Abwaad', 'Abwabd', 'Abwacd', 'Abwadd', 'Abwaed', 'Abwafd', 'Abwagd', 'Abwahd', 'Abwaid', 'Abwajd', 'Abwakd', 'Abwald', 'Abwamd', 'Abwand', 'Abwaod', 'Abwapd', 'Abwaqd', 'Abward', 'Abwasd', 'Abwatd', 'Abwaud', 'Abwavd', 'Abwawd', 'Abwaxd', 'Abwayd', 'Abwazd', 'Acwaad', 'Acwabd', 'Acwacd', 'Acwadd', 'Acwaed', 'Acwafd', 'Acwagd', 'Acwahd', 'Acwaid', 'Acwajd', 'Acwakd', 'Acwald', 'Acwamd', 'Acwand', 'Acwaod', 'Acwapd', 'Acwaqd', 'Acward', 'Acwasd', 'Acwatd', 'Acwaud', 'Acwavd', 'Acwawd', 'Acwaxd', 'Acwayd', 'Acwazd', 'Adwaad', 'Adwabd', 'Adwacd', 'Adwadd', 'Adwaed', 'Adwafd', 'Adwagd', 'Adwahd', 'Adwaid', 'Adwajd', 'Adwakd', 'Adwald', 'Adwamd', 'Adwand', 'Adwaod', 'Adwapd', 'Adwaqd', 'Adward', 'Adwasd', 'Adwatd', 'Adwaud', 'Adwavd', 'Adwawd', 'Adwaxd', 'Adwayd', 'Adwazd', 'Aewaad', 'Aewabd', 'Aewacd', 'Aewadd', 'Aewaed', 'Aewafd', 'Aewagd', 'Aewahd', 'Aewaid', 'Aewajd', 'Aewakd', 'Aewald', 'Aewamd', 'Aewand', 'Aewaod', 'Aewapd', 'Aewaqd', 'Aeward', 'Aewasd', 'Aewatd', 'Aewaud', 'Aewavd', 'Aewawd', 'Aewaxd', 'Aewayd', 'Aewazd', 'Afwaad', 'Afwabd', 'Afwacd', 'Afwadd', 'Afwaed', 'Afwafd', 'Afwagd', 'Afwahd', 'Afwaid', 'Afwajd', 'Afwakd', 'Afwald', 'Afwamd', 'Afwand', 'Afwaod', 'Afwapd', 'Afwaqd', 'Afward', 'Afwasd', 'Afwatd', 'Afwaud', 'Afwavd', 'Afwawd', 'Afwaxd', 'Afwayd', 'Afwazd', 'Agwaad', 'Agwabd', 'Agwacd', 'Agwadd', 'Agwaed', 'Agwafd', 'Agwagd', 'Agwahd', 'Agwaid', 'Agwajd', 'Agwakd', 'Agwald', 'Agwamd', 'Agwand', 'Agwaod', 'Agwapd', 'Agwaqd', 'Agward', 'Agwasd', 'Agwatd', 'Agwaud', 'Agwavd', 'Agwawd', 'Agwaxd', 'Agwayd', 'Agwazd', 'Ahwaad', 'Ahwabd', 'Ahwacd', 'Ahwadd', 'Ahwaed', 'Ahwafd', 'Ahwagd', 'Ahwahd', 'Ahwaid', 'Ahwajd', 'Ahwakd', 'Ahwald', 'Ahwamd', 'Ahwand', 'Ahwaod', 'Ahwapd', 'Ahwaqd', 'Ahward', 'Ahwasd', 'Ahwatd', 'Ahwaud', 'Ahwavd', 'Ahwawd', 'Ahwaxd', 'Ahwayd', 'Ahwazd', 'Aiwaad', 'Aiwabd', 'Aiwacd', 'Aiwadd', 'Aiwaed', 'Aiwafd', 'Aiwagd', 'Aiwahd', 'Aiwaid', 'Aiwajd', 'Aiwakd', 'Aiwald', 'Aiwamd', 'Aiwand', 'Aiwaod', 'Aiwapd', 'Aiwaqd', 'Aiward', 'Aiwasd', 'Aiwatd', 'Aiwaud', 'Aiwavd', 'Aiwawd', 'Aiwaxd', 'Aiwayd', 'Aiwazd', 'Ajwaad', 'Ajwabd', 'Ajwacd', 'Ajwadd', 'Ajwaed', 'Ajwafd', 'Ajwagd', 'Ajwahd', 'Ajwaid', 'Ajwajd', 'Ajwakd', 'Ajwald', 'Ajwamd', 'Ajwand', 'Ajwaod', 'Ajwapd', 'Ajwaqd', 'Ajward', 'Ajwasd', 'Ajwatd', 'Ajwaud', 'Ajwavd', 'Ajwawd', 'Ajwaxd', 'Ajwayd', 'Ajwazd', 'Akwaad', 'Akwabd', 'Akwacd', 'Akwadd', 'Akwaed', 'Akwafd', 'Akwagd', 'Akwahd', 'Akwaid', 'Akwajd', 'Akwakd', 'Akwald', 'Akwamd', 'Akwand', 'Akwaod', 'Akwapd', 'Akwaqd', 'Akward', 'Akwasd', 'Akwatd', 'Akwaud', 'Akwavd', 'Akwawd', 'Akwaxd', 'Akwayd', 'Akwazd', 'Alwaad', 'Alwabd', 'Alwacd', 'Alwadd', 'Alwaed', 'Alwafd', 'Alwagd', 'Alwahd', 'Alwaid', 'Alwajd', 'Alwakd', 'Alwald', 'Alwamd', 'Alwand', 'Alwaod', 'Alwapd', 'Alwaqd', 'Alward', 'Alwasd', 'Alwatd', 'Alwaud', 'Alwavd', 'Alwawd', 'Alwaxd', 'Alwayd', 'Alwazd', 'Amwaad', 'Amwabd', 'Amwacd', 'Amwadd', 'Amwaed', 'Amwafd', 'Amwagd', 'Amwahd', 'Amwaid', 'Amwajd', 'Amwakd', 'Amwald', 'Amwamd', 'Amwand', 'Amwaod', 'Amwapd', 'Amwaqd', 'Amward', 'Amwasd', 'Amwatd', 'Amwaud', 'Amwavd', 'Amwawd', 'Amwaxd', 'Amwayd', 'Amwazd', 'Anwaad', 'Anwabd', 'Anwacd', 'Anwadd', 'Anwaed', 'Anwafd', 'Anwagd', 'Anwahd', 'Anwaid', 'Anwajd', 'Anwakd', 'Anwald', 'Anwamd', 'Anwand', 'Anwaod', 'Anwapd', 'Anwaqd', 'Anward', 'Anwasd', 'Anwatd', 'Anwaud', 'Anwavd', 'Anwawd', 'Anwaxd', 'Anwayd', 'Anwazd', 'Aowaad', 'Aowabd', 'Aowacd', 'Aowadd', 'Aowaed', 'Aowafd', 'Aowagd', 'Aowahd', 'Aowaid', 'Aowajd', 'Aowakd', 'Aowald', 'Aowamd', 'Aowand', 'Aowaod', 'Aowapd', 'Aowaqd', 'Aoward', 'Aowasd', 'Aowatd', 'Aowaud', 'Aowavd', 'Aowawd', 'Aowaxd', 'Aowayd', 'Aowazd', 'Apwaad', 'Apwabd', 'Apwacd', 'Apwadd', 'Apwaed', 'Apwafd', 'Apwagd', 'Apwahd', 'Apwaid', 'Apwajd', 'Apwakd', 'Apwald', 'Apwamd', 'Apwand', 'Apwaod', 'Apwapd', 'Apwaqd', 'Apward', 'Apwasd', 'Apwatd', 'Apwaud', 'Apwavd', 'Apwawd', 'Apwaxd', 'Apwayd', 'Apwazd', 'Aqwaad', 'Aqwabd', 'Aqwacd', 'Aqwadd', 'Aqwaed', 'Aqwafd', 'Aqwagd', 'Aqwahd', 'Aqwaid', 'Aqwajd', 'Aqwakd', 'Aqwald', 'Aqwamd', 'Aqwand', 'Aqwaod', 'Aqwapd', 'Aqwaqd', 'Aqward', 'Aqwasd', 'Aqwatd', 'Aqwaud', 'Aqwavd', 'Aqwawd', 'Aqwaxd', 'Aqwayd', 'Aqwazd', 'Arwaad', 'Arwabd', 'Arwacd', 'Arwadd', 'Arwaed', 'Arwafd', 'Arwagd', 'Arwahd', 'Arwaid', 'Arwajd', 'Arwakd', 'Arwald', 'Arwamd', 'Arwand', 'Arwaod', 'Arwapd', 'Arwaqd', 'Arward', 'Arwasd', 'Arwatd', 'Arwaud', 'Arwavd', 'Arwawd', 'Arwaxd', 'Arwayd', 'Arwazd', 'Aswaad', 'Aswabd', 'Aswacd', 'Aswadd', 'Aswaed', 'Aswafd', 'Aswagd', 'Aswahd', 'Aswaid', 'Aswajd', 'Aswakd', 'Aswald', 'Aswamd', 'Aswand', 'Aswaod', 'Aswapd', 'Aswaqd', 'Asward', 'Aswasd', 'Aswatd', 'Aswaud', 'Aswavd', 'Aswawd', 'Aswaxd', 'Aswayd', 'Aswazd', 'Atwaad', 'Atwabd', 'Atwacd', 'Atwadd', 'Atwaed', 'Atwafd', 'Atwagd', 'Atwahd', 'Atwaid', 'Atwajd', 'Atwakd', 'Atwald', 'Atwamd', 'Atwand', 'Atwaod', 'Atwapd', 'Atwaqd', 'Atward', 'Atwasd', 'Atwatd', 'Atwaud', 'Atwavd', 'Atwawd', 'Atwaxd', 'Atwayd', 'Atwazd', 'Auwaad', 'Auwabd', 'Auwacd', 'Auwadd', 'Auwaed', 'Auwafd', 'Auwagd', 'Auwahd', 'Auwaid', 'Auwajd', 'Auwakd', 'Auwald', 'Auwamd', 'Auwand', 'Auwaod', 'Auwapd', 'Auwaqd', 'Auward', 'Auwasd', 'Auwatd', 'Auwaud', 'Auwavd', 'Auwawd', 'Auwaxd', 'Auwayd', 'Auwazd', 'Avwaad', 'Avwabd', 'Avwacd', 'Avwadd', 'Avwaed', 'Avwafd', 'Avwagd', 'Avwahd', 'Avwaid', 'Avwajd', 'Avwakd', 'Avwald', 'Avwamd', 'Avwand', 'Avwaod', 'Avwapd', 'Avwaqd', 'Avward', 'Avwasd', 'Avwatd', 'Avwaud', 'Avwavd', 'Avwawd', 'Avwaxd', 'Avwayd', 'Avwazd', 'Awwaad', 'Awwabd', 'Awwacd', 'Awwadd', 'Awwaed', 'Awwafd', 'Awwagd', 'Awwahd', 'Awwaid', 'Awwajd', 'Awwakd', 'Awwald', 'Awwamd', 'Awwand', 'Awwaod', 'Awwapd', 'Awwaqd', 'Awward', 'Awwasd', 'Awwatd', 'Awwaud', 'Awwavd', 'Awwawd', 'Awwaxd', 'Awwayd', 'Awwazd', 'Axwaad', 'Axwabd', 'Axwacd', 'Axwadd', 'Axwaed', 'Axwafd', 'Axwagd', 'Axwahd', 'Axwaid', 'Axwajd', 'Axwakd', 'Axwald', 'Axwamd', 'Axwand', 'Axwaod', 'Axwapd', 'Axwaqd', 'Axward', 'Axwasd', 'Axwatd', 'Axwaud', 'Axwavd', 'Axwawd', 'Axwaxd', 'Axwayd', 'Axwazd', 'Aywaad', 'Aywabd', 'Aywacd', 'Aywadd', 'Aywaed', 'Aywafd', 'Aywagd', 'Aywahd', 'Aywaid', 'Aywajd', 'Aywakd', 'Aywald', 'Aywamd', 'Aywand', 'Aywaod', 'Aywapd', 'Aywaqd', 'Ayward', 'Aywasd', 'Aywatd', 'Aywaud', 'Aywavd', 'Aywawd', 'Aywaxd', 'Aywayd', 'Aywazd', 'Azwaad', 'Azwabd', 'Azwacd', 'Azwadd', 'Azwaed', 'Azwafd', 'Azwagd', 'Azwahd', 'Azwaid', 'Azwajd', 'Azwakd', 'Azwald', 'Azwamd', 'Azwand', 'Azwaod', 'Azwapd', 'Azwaqd', 'Azward', 'Azwasd', 'Azwatd', 'Azwaud', 'Azwavd', 'Azwawd', 'Azwaxd', 'Azwayd', 'Azwazd']
676
```

Comment: You could directly iterate over the alphabet, not indice then access via index